# Is it possible see volume in Docker as device?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mount, docker-volume

I have a script used in production that does basically this:

```
make.ext4 ... /dev/sdb1
mount /dev/sdb1 /folder
and so on
```

I have a Docker environment where I simulate my production environment. Now, what I need is the possibility to use the same script on both the env. To do that, I need the possibility in Docker to have a /dev/sdb1 device and attach on it a volume in some way, so that when I run the commands above my volume is attached to /folder.

I know this can be done easily with:

```
docker run -t <tag> -v <my volume>:/folder -it /bin/bash
```

But in this way, things are a little different in Docker container and I need to modify my script (In my case I have several scripts to change).

Is there a way to do something like:

```
docker run -t <tag> -v <my volume>:/dev/sdb1 -it /bin/bash
```

so that when in Docker I do:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /folder
```

I mount my external volume to /folder in the container?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run docker with privileges to do mount?

Maybe if you launch `docker run --privileged` or `docker run --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN`, you have /dev/sdb1 accessible from docker, so, is possible to do `mount /dev/sdb1/`

For further information about docker container privileges, please, see: [Docker Documentation privileged mode and capabilities](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#additional-groups)

Comment: Yes, I tried and it worked but the problem is that on Mac Docker runs on a Linux VM and when you run: ```docker run --privileged -v ...``` the folder is correctly mounted. On Linux VM the volume is on /var/lib/docker/volume/<hash>. You can unmount it but when you remount it using sdb1 it mount /var/lib instead of /var/lib/docker/volume/<hash>. I do not know how to tell to mount command that I do not need the whole /dev/sdb1 (/var/lib on Linux VM) but its subfolder /var/lib/docker/volume/<hash>

Comment: Yes, I have tried. I see the volume mounted and I can even unmount it. But if I mount again using /dev/sdb1 it mount /var/lib on my Linux VM (on Mac) instead of /var/lib/docker/volume/<volume name> I need a way to tell to mount command to mount /var/lib/docker/volume/<volume name> instead of /var/lib but it's not clear to me how to do that.

Comment: The thing is that /var/lib/docker/volume/<volume name> is in the same mounting point that /var/lib is not possible to work with them separatedly. You need to use different mounting points for both or is not possible to unmount one without the other.

Comment: Probably I didn't explain correctly my problem. Whenever you create a volume in Docker it is created in /var/lib/docker/volume/<volume name> on Linux VM. Suppose you create two volumes V1 and V2 and you mount them on different mount points on Docker image /folder1 and /folder2. If you run the mount command with no parameters you see that both mounts have /dev/sdb1 as a device. Now /dev/sdb1 on Linux VM is mapped with /var/lib. In fact, if you try to unmount both the folders and mount /dev/sdb1 on folder1 you'll see in it the content of /var/lib and this is unexpected from my point of view.

Comment: That's why, as I told before, when you mount a volume in docker **is not the same** than linux mount. Linux uses 1 mounting point and docker several "virtual" mounting points (internal symlink) for 1 single linux mount point.

Comment: Do you know any workaround to overcome this limitation?

Comment: There's no way. You need to use different linux mounting points for each docker volume to mount. Otherwise both volumes will be assigned to the same linux mounting point and you couldn't unmount it.

Comment: But I already do this. I have volume 1 on /folder1 and volume 2 on /folder2. On Linux VM volume 1 in under /var/lib/docker/volume/volume1 and volume 2 is under /var/lib/docker/volume/volume2. If I run "mount" I see /dev/sdb1 /folder1 .... /dev/sdb1 /folder2. If I do "umount /folder1" it works. If I do "mount /dev/sdb1 /folder1" under /folder 1 I do not see the content of Linux VM /var/lib/docker/volume/volume1 but the content of whole /var/lib.

Comment: Yes, that what I said, the only way is using different linux mounting points, just that, /dev/sdb1 and /deb/sdb2. So, what's your problem? Don't you have it already solved? I can't get you, sorry

Comment: My problem is that I do not have control of which device docker define for my mount point. I do not tell anywhere to associate /dev/sdb1 for my two mount points, it does this by itself. Is there a way when I create a virtual volume to associate a device in Docker?

Comment: I'm affraid there's no way to do that because always you create a docker volume, it's mapped to /var/lib/docker/volumes/, which already belongs to a mounting point. 
Have you tried to mount for example `/dev/sdb1` in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<your_volume>/_data` before doing `docker volume create <your_volume>`?

Comment: On Linux VM? No.